# How can I recover a variable-length number of GET variables via PHP?

Tags: php, get

In many languages, you can have variable-length argument lists to functions (eg [printf](/questions/tagged/printf) in [c](/questions/tagged/c)).

In a current [php](/questions/tagged/php) application I am working on, I have a desire to process X-many variables coming-in via HTTP GET. I am wondering if I need to follow something like [DuckDuckGo](http://ddg.gg)'s GET query format (`?q=find+many+things`), and parse the results breaking on the intervening character (in this case a `+` sign), or if there is a way to create a list of incoming variables that might look something like:

```
?t0=find&t1=many&t2=things
```

all the way out to `tn` items which I could iterate through *a la* using `argv` and `argc` in command-line applications.

#### Question:

- is there a way to process `argc`-many items via GET with PHP?
- if not, is there a method *other than* the `variable=..+..+..` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$_GET` is just an associative array.  You can iterate over it like any other.

```
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {

}
```

Comment: thanks - somehow I missed that in the docs. Follow-up/clarification: is this "better" than the long-string-with-separators method?

Comment: @warren I would say so.  PHP already does the parsing, and the query-string format is very clear.  If you have some string with separators, you have then manage your own escape characters and what not.  Something you might also consider if you need more structure, is JSON sent as a POST.